# What would be the best phrase for meeting on-site (in contrast to remote / web meetings)?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

As far as I understand there are several phrases possible:

"We want to ..."

- "meet in person"
- "meet on site" / "meet on-site"
- "meet locally"
- "meet physically"
- "meet face-to-face"

Is there a difference in the meaning?

Is there helpful guidance when should I use which phrase?

Comment: I like “in person” as less threatening than “face to face” and also playing down location.

Comment: "in person" is also a common way to say it.